# Load a new page after another finishes loading

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

In my company we have a web-based tool that you enter an account, press a button, and the page takes a little bit to load, then loads account information.  There are several different pages that do the same thing but load different information.  I have already been able to make the sites load with direct URL execution (with an intermediate page and some JavaScript) so I only have to enter their account number once.  My problem is, I want them to pull up all at the same time to speed things up, but there is some kind of lock that does not let you run the lookup in two pages at once.  I want to make my site load the first page, then wait til it loads and immediately begin loading the next page in another tab on my page.  Is that even possible in HTML and JavaScript?  If so how, if not, what other language do I need to learn today?

Comment: do you mean with 'another tab' a tab in the browser? Or a "tab" inside your current html page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out the jquery's $(document).ready();

simply use

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 //execute script that calls another page, you could use ajax 


});
```

other method is using iframes, which i personally don't recommend

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like [Pageflakes](http://www.pageflakes.com/Default.aspx)?

If so, you will need to utilise AJAX (and/or webservices). A good tutorial/source code on building something like this is at [DropThings](http://dropthings.codeplex.com/) (which is from the same author as PageFlakes).
This is using ASP.NET C# and AJAX Control Toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

If the two URLs are loaded into separate `<iframe>` elements then you just need to create a `load` event handler for the first frame to set the `src` attribute of the second frame.